# Отображение контейнера QVariantList в ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Столкнулся с проблемой во время написания практики в университете. Пишем банковскую систему, со стороны "плюсов" передаем двумерный QVariantList, вот метод, который его возвращает(данные беруться из БД):

```
QVariantList Controller::cardsToQML() {
    std::vector<Card> cards = client.getCards();
    emit Controller::test();
    QVariantList cards_to_qml;
    int number_of_cards = 0;
    foreach (Card card, cards) {
        //        emit Controller::cardToQML(
        //            card.getNumber(), card.getHolderName(), card.getType(), card.getValid(), card.getBalance());
        QVariantList card_variant;
        card_variant.push_back(card.getNumber());
        card_variant.push_back(card.getHolderName());
        card_variant.push_back(card.getType());
        card_variant.push_back(card.getValid());
        card_variant.push_back(card.getBalance());
        cards_to_qml.push_back(card_variant);
        number_of_cards++;
    }
    cards_to_qml.insert(0, number_of_cards);
    return cards_to_qml;
}
```

Вот часть нашего ListView, где в роли model используется наш контейнер, однако никак не получается использовать информацию, находящуюся в нем:

```
ListView {
                id: lv
                height: 240
                width: 500
                anchors {
                    top: finance_text.top
                    left: finance.left
                    right: finance.right
                    margins: 40
                }
                highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
                clip: true
                snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                delegate: card_delegate

                model: Controller.cardsToQML()
```

Вот один из примеров наших попыток изъять информацию:

```
Text {
                                    id: balance
                                    anchors {
                                        left: balance_text.right
                                        leftMargin: 15
                                        verticalCenter: balance_text.verticalCenter
                                    }
                                    font.pixelSize: 60
                                    // font.bold: true
                                    text: model[1][1] // model.balance
                                    color: "white"
                                }
```

Можете ли подсказать, как правильно работать с такими комплексными контейнерами?

Comment: а в чем проблема и собственно вопрос...я не совсем понял

Comment: добавьте в описание определение и имплементацию класса Controller, так будет легче найти проблему